# skip a task in gradle, but only if the task exists

Tags: gradle

I have a complex multi sub-project gradle project with a little kotlin multiplatform inside and a fex custom gradle plugin.

My issue is , when I want to run the build by skipping some tasks(mostly test), not all the project have the same test task name : for some it's call jsTest, for other nodeJsTest, for other jvmTest.

So when I call `gradle build -x jsTest -x nodeJsTest` I have error because sometime some of the tasks to skip don't exist.

**How can I skip the task, and ignore-it if it don't exist?**

Comment: Can't you just run the tasks you need, like `gradle assemble`? If not, I would recommend adding custom "aggregation" tasks that depend on what you want to run.

Comment: no, it's task who depend of other task : by exemple tests task are launched at each build

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Gradle file to do something like (Kotlin DSL):

```
tasks.named("build") {
    dependsOn.removeIf { it.toString().contains("flakyTest") }
}
```

Otherwise you will need to aggregate your tasks to what you want specifically either by doing `./gradlew myTask anotherTask anotherOne andAnotherOne` or create a task that `dependsOn` all the tasks you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your test tasks to depend on build directly, you can create generic test task `task testType` in the middle- build triggers `task testType` and then it triggers `jsTest` or whatever relevant test task you create in that module.
Now you can safely run `gradle build -x testType`.

For example (in your .gradle file):

```
task jsTest { ... }
task testType { dependsOn jsTest }
build.finalizedBy(testType)
```

Do the same for the rest of your test tasks files, you can also create `task testType` globaly if you want the solution to be cleaner.